# Criar variáveis e preencher com informações de outras variáveis

Tags: r

Software R. Gostaria de saber como crio variáveis através de informações contidas em uma variável e depois preencher com informações que estão em outras duas existentes. 
Exemplo

[image: Como esta]

Gostaria que ficasse assim
[image: Como eu gostaria que estivesse]

Desculpa a maneira da pergunta, estou aprendendo. As imagens são exemplos

Comment: Procure colocar seus dados em um formato que seja facilmente reproduzível pelos usuários do SO. Você pode manter as imagens, para facilitar a visualização, mas experimente rodar `dput(head(seus.dados))` e cole a saída na pergunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A função `reshape2::dcast` faz o que necessita. Só terá que rodá-la uma vez para cada semestre e unir os dados:

```
dados <- data.frame(
  id = c(rep(9039, 2), rep(8234, 2)),
  semestre_1 = paste(1, 2018:2017, sep = '_'),
  semestre_2 = paste(2, 2018:2017, sep = '_'),
  para_1s = 1:4,
  para_2s = 5:8
)

> dados
    id semestre_1 semestre_2 para_1s para_2s
1 9039     1_2018     2_2018       1       5
2 9039     1_2017     2_2017       2       6
3 8234     1_2018     2_2018       3       7
4 8234     1_2017     2_2017       4       8

library(reshape2)
sem1 <- dcast(dados, id ~ semestre_1, value.var = 'para_1s')
sem2 <- dcast(dados, id ~ semestre_2, value.var = 'para_2s')

> merge(sem1, sem2)
    id 1_2017 1_2018 2_2017 2_2018
1 8234      4      3      8      7
2 9039      2      1      6      5
```